# What does the SCARD_W_UNRESPONSIVE_CARD error on GlobalPlatform Pro indicate about the state of the card?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, globalplatform

I'm getting this message `SCARD_W_UNRESPONSIVE_CARD` when trying to do anything with a specific ACOSJ card.

I have a card reader that I'm using with multiple cards of the same type, no problems, and no problems with the other ACOSJ cards either. What does this error mean? Is the card not getting an ATR? What are the possible reasons for this and how can I fix it/debug it if I can't communicate with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this error occasionally and the only reason in my case is that the contacts of the card are not properly placed. In this case the card must be reinserted or is in general too thin. In case of a SIM this happens when the nano SIM was already broken out and is not reinserted properly again. Maybe there is also a problem with the voltage being the real underlying cause of this.

Comment: Ah okay - that would make sense as it hasn't ever worked, so I did suspect it might have been a physical issue with the card. Is there anything you've done to fix it or does it just mean this card is a dud?

Comment: The card could be dead. But I would also try a different card reader. On of my readers is giving the card a tighter hold. If it is an issue of the card thickness or the contacts I would try this first.

Comment: I'll try another reader, thank you